# Definition of a quirky update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Based on Itzik Ben-Gan's article in [ITProToday](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you)

> Microsoft’s implementation follows the physical data independence
>   principle, and therefore does not guarantee that you will get the data
>   back from a query in any particular order unless you add an ORDER BY
>   clause in the outer query. A similar violation of the principle is
>   when people update data and the solution’s correctness relies on the
>   data being updated in clustered index order (do a Web search on
>   “**quirky update**” to see what I mean).

I tried to find what a quirky update means but in vain.
I am looking for an example to understand the concept.

Comment: Read this paper https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten by the inventor of “quirky update”.

Comment: Where the author purport to "proove" that this undocumented method is reliable by providing several examples where it happened to work as he expects.

Comment: well, then provide at least one reasonable case where it doesn't work, but satisfies all the other conditions that Moden put on it to make it work. 

Moden didn't invent it. It is legacy code from the Sybase code days, and was "invented" in that space first, and presumably still used there.

In that light, at a former employer, I ran into some TSQL code there that used "legacy" join syntax, that was quite a bit faster than equivalent ANSI JOIN syntax. In the cases where it was used, and the data sets were large, it was a significant difference, so I dropped it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of the "Quirky Update"

```
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists t
go
create table t(id int primary key, Amount int, RunningTotal int)

insert into t(id,Amount,RunningTotal) values (1,4,0),(2,2,0),(3,6,0)

declare @t int = 0

update t set @t = RunningTotal = @t + Amount

select * from t
```

outputs

```
id          Amount      RunningTotal
----------- ----------- ------------
1           4           4
2           2           6
3           6           12
```