# How to apply row_number for each partition with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I want to add a column named PLRowNo which is row number of PL actype in each voucher group. I also want the numbering to start from 1 for every voucher number.

This is the expected result

```
| id | voucherID | actype | PLRowNo |
|----|-----------| -------|---------|
| 1  | voucher01 | BS     |         |
| 2  | voucher01 | PL     | 1       |
| 3  | voucher01 | BS     |         |
| 4  | voucher01 | PL     | 2       |
| 5  | voucher01 | PL     | 3       |
| 6  | voucher01 | BS     |         |       
| 7  | voucher01 | PL     | 4       |
| 8  | voucher01 | BS     |         |
| 9  | voucher01 | PL     | 5       |
| 10 | voucher02 | PL     |         |
| 11 | voucher02 | PL     | 1       |
| 12 | voucher02 | BS     |         |
| 13 | voucher02 | PL     | 2       |
```

This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_tmp (
    id int not null primary key,
    voucherID nvarchar(10) not null,
    actype nvarchar(10) not null
);

insert into tbl_tmp(id,voucherID, actype)
values (1,'voucher01', 'BS'),
        (2,'voucher01', 'PL'),
        (3,'voucher01', 'BS'),
        (4,'voucher01', 'PL'),
        (5,'voucher01', 'PL'),
        (6,'voucher01', 'BS'),
        (7,'voucher01', 'PL'),
        (8,'voucher01', 'BS'),
        (9,'voucher01', 'PL'),
        (10,'voucher02', 'PL'),
        (11,'voucher02', 'PL'),
        (12,'voucher02', 'BS'),
        (13,'voucher02', 'PL')

select *,0 as PLRowNo into #tmp from tbl_tmp
declare @id int set @id=0

update #tmp
set @id= case when actype ='PL' then @id+1   else 0 end,
 PLRowNo = case when actype='PL' then @id else 0 end

select * from #tmp
```

The problem with this query is, it starts counting from 1 (id: 13) if the previous row's type is 'BS'even though in the same voucher partition. I want the continuation within one voucher.

This is the wrong result

```
| id | voucherID | actype | PLRowNo |
|----|-----------| -------|---------|
| 1  | voucher01 | BS     |         |
| 2  | voucher01 | PL     | 1       |
| 3  | voucher01 | BS     |         |
| 4  | voucher01 | PL     | 2       |
| 5  | voucher01 | PL     | 3       |
| 6  | voucher01 | BS     |         |       
| 7  | voucher01 | PL     | 4       |
| 8  | voucher01 | BS     |         |
| 9  | voucher01 | PL     | 5       |
| 10 | voucher02 | PL     |         |
| 11 | voucher02 | PL     | 1       |
| 12 | voucher02 | BS     |         |
| 13 | voucher02 | PL     | 1       |
```

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO textual code-formatted scripts, screenshot does not allow to copy the data. Provide desired output table-formatted.

Comment: Select one DBMS (your SQL code claims that you use SQL Server) and remove excess tag. Specify precise DBMS version.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need temp tables or [quirky updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030329/definition-of-a-quirky-update), you can just use `ROW_NUMBER`

```sql
SELECT *,
  PLRow_no = CASE WHEN actype = 'PL' THEN
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY actype, voucherID ORDER BY id) 
    END
FROM tbl_tmp
ORDER BY id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f48c25fe14120cad38aa46d93f097d05)

Comment: Thank you. This works and it is simpler than I thought.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

```
select *,    
CASE
    WHEN actype='PL' THEN CAST((select count(*) from tbl_tmp as t where actype='PL' and t.id<=tbl_tmp.id and  t.voucherID=tbl_tmp.voucherID )as VarChar(10))
    ELSE ''
END
as PLRowNo     
from tbl_tmp
```

Comment: This works too. Although I don't understand the code.  Thank you.